# copy csv postgres ignore rows that violate constraints

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I have a .csv file with ~300,000 rows, some of which violate certain constraints I set in my postgres database. Is there a way to copy my .csv file into the database and have postgres filter out the rows that violate the constraints? I do not want these rows to show up in the database.

If this is not possible, is there any other way to solve this problem?

what I'm doing right now is

```
COPY blocksequences from '/tmp/blocksequences.csv CSV HEADER;
```

And I get

```
'ERROR:  new row for relation "blocksequences" violates check constraint "blocksequences_partid3_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (M001-M049-S186, M001, null, M049, S186).
CONTEXT:  COPY blocksequences, line 680: "M001-M049-S186,M001,,M049,S186"
```

reason for the error: column that contains M049 is not allowed to have that string entered. Many other rows have violations like this.

I read a little about `exception when check violation --do nothing` am I on the right track here? seems like it's only a mysql thing maybe

Comment: that seems like a good idea, but I'm wondering how I would go about deleting rows that dont fulfil constraints? the idea is I would rather not have to brute force delete since there are so many rows..

Comment: oh of course! Stupid of me not to think of this... thank you. If you'll write an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually this is done in this way:

- create a temporary table with the same structure as the destination one but without constraints,
- copy data to the temporary table with `COPY` command,
- copy rows that do fulfill constraints from temp table to the destination one, using `INSERT` command with conditions in the `WHERE` clause based on the table constraint,
- drop the temporary table.

When dealing with really large CSV files or very limited server resources, use the [extension file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) instead of temporary tables. It's much more efficient way but it requires server access to a CSV file (while copying to a temporary table can be done over the network).

In **Postgres 12** you can use the `WHERE` clause in [`COPY FROM.`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html)